# Error with Walker_Nav_Menu

Tags: php, wordpress

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '(' in C:\wamp\www\home\wordpress\wp-content\themes\tourpackage-v2-00\include\plugin\dropdown-menus.php on line 133

Code:

function start_el (&$output, $depth = 0, $args = Array)

Comment: This isn't a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

`Array` is invalid.

Change this:

```
function start_el (&$output, $depth = 0, $args = Array)
```

To this:

```
function start_el( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() )
```

Comment: Thank you. Should I add the same in the output as well..

Comment: '$output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_dropdown_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );'

Comment: May I send you the php file?

Comment: No, the output line you've posted is fine as is.

Comment: M still getting an error.